# Unsafe Object binding Checkmarx Java

Tags: java, security, checkmarx

I am getting alert in Checkmarx scan saying Unsafe object binding in the saveAll() call. The exact words in checkmarx are

```
The orderReqDto at src/main/java/com/coppel/omnicanal/coppelpay/controller/ValidarClienteController.java in line 69
may unintentionally allow setting the value of saveAll in validarPlazosCliente, in the object
src/main/java/com/coppel/omnicanal/coppelpay/bussines/CustomerValidationBussines.java at line 392.
```

Any idea how to rewrite the code , so that the checkmarx stops complaining.

My code:

```
@PostMapping("/pos/num-cliente")
    public BaseResponseDTO<CustomerValidationRespDto<PlazoDto>> validateCustomerPosNumCliente(@Valid @RequestBody NumClienteReqDto orderReqDto, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
        // * Obtiene data de JWT de interceptor
        JwtDto data = (JwtDto) req.getAttribute(DATA_DTO);
        return compraBussines.validarCliente(orderReqDto.getNumCliente(), null, data, null);
    }
```

```
412. clientePlazosDao.saveAll(plazosValidos);
```

Need fix this vulnerability.